# onEditorAction is not called in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I generated this activity using the Android Studio Navigation Drawer preset, so the EditText is inside a fragment. What I'm trying to do is to create a notification after the "Send" button is pressed on the keyboard. When I click the button nothing happens, the onEditorAction is not called. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

```
inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
EditText noteText = (EditText) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.write_note);

noteText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;

            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                createNotification();
                handled = true;
            }
            return handled;
        }
    });
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/write_note"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_outline"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#c8ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="@string/edit_text_hint" />
```

Answer (score 1):

do this way,please set "android:imeOptions="actionSend" in edittext.

```
 noteText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
            {
                boolean handled = false;

                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND)
                {
                    createNotification();

                    handled = true;
                }
                return handled;
            }
        });
```

put this into xml,

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:singleLine="true" />
```

This works for me. You can hide the soft keyboard after made the calculations using a code like this:

```
InputMethodManager imm= (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: It didn't work, for debugging purpose I added `noteText.setHint("write text Here!!!!");` under the onCreate method and it didn't change the placeholder text so I think that the problem is that it doesn't recognize the EditText in the Activity from the xml file. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Ok problem solved, I was putting everything in the wrong place: the Activity.onCreate instead that the Fragment.onCreateView. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:imeOptions="actionSend"` in xml of edittext and let us know if it helps

Comment: It was already there, I'll edit the question with the xml file

Answer (score 0):

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_address, container, false);
 editText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_country);
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(
            new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                            actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                            event != null &&
                                    event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                                    event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
```

{ if (event == null || !event.isShiftPressed()) {
                                // the user is done typing. 
                                return true; // consume.
                        }
                        return false; // pass on to other listeners. 
                    }
                }
   );